# confirm cancel button not working for this simple code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

The confirm/cancel button is not working, I don't know what the issue is.

Even after clicking the confirm box cancel it's still directing me to another page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>password</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function f() {
                if (myform.password.value == "") {
                    window.alert("you need to enter your password");
                } else {
                    window.confirm("are you sure u want to proceed");
                    window.location =' https://www.facebook.com/';
                }
            }
        </script>
        <center>
            <h1>confirm password page</h1>
            <form id="myform">
                Enter the Password
                <input type="password" id="password" value="">
                <input type="button" id="continue" value ="continue" onclick="f()">
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.confirm` returns boolean, so wrap it in an if statement

Comment: Bit of a HTML hiccup there with the `</centre>` element

Comment: @IanH. It is always DANGEROUS to change the code!! Format it so its readable by all means but moving lines about or in any way changing the logic is a **Big NoNo**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't think I changed it? Just fixed the indendation and removed the trailing codeblock.

Comment: @IanH. You move the `</center>` to its logical position from where is originally was. Fairly trivial, but a bad habit to get into

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ah sorry, habit of nature. Haven't edited posts in a while. I'll roll back.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
if(window.confirm("are you sure u want to proceed")) {
      // Proceed to next page
}
```

The confirm() method displays a dialog box with a message, an OK button, and a Cancel button.

The confirm() method returns true if the user clicked "OK", otherwise false.

Answer (score 1):

**Window.confirm()** returns a **boolean**.

- if **ok** clicked then **true**.
- if **cancel** clicked then **false**.

So you have to handle like a if-else block.

```
if(window.confirm("are you sure u want to proceed")){
// your redirection logic here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it

```js
function f(){
  if(myform.password.value==""){
    window.alert("you need to enter your password");
  }
  else{
    if (window.confirm("are you sure u want to proceed")) {
      window.location =' https://www.facebook.com/';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>confirm password page </h1>
  <form id="myform">
    Enter the Password<input type="password" id="password" value="">
    <input type="button" id="continue" value ="continue" onclick="f()">
  </form>
</center>
```

Comment: Please have a quick read of this [How to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Thank you i will read it when i free

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of form cause the direction to an another page. for preventing that behavior you should use `preventDefault()` on your form. like:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

here is a sample:

https://codepen.io/navab/pen/YzemrWB

Answer (score 0):

just copy-paste my code it will return you back when u press cancel

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>password</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function f() {
                if (myform.password.value == "") {
                    window.alert("you need to enter your password");
                } else {
                    if(window.confirm("are you sure u want to proceed")==true){
                    window.location =' https://www.facebook.com/';}
                    else{
                      window.location.reload();
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <center>
            <h1>confirm password page</h1>
            <form id="myform">
                Enter the Password
                <input type="password" id="password" value="">
                <input type="button" id="continue" value ="continue" onclick="f()">
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: What is different between this answer and the answer give 33 minutes ago by @ujwalkadariya ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).